# Regex find all of the last varying strings before each of the unique strings

Tags: regex

I want to find regex for this application. I have searched but could not find the answer but I am not an expert in regex. I  will try to explain what I want to do. I want a regex to find all of the last url before each of the unique strings

I tried (?!href).*(?<=Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters) but it hangs the program when using the actual html maybe because it is a lot longer than my example here.

In this example I want to find all of the last partial urls before the Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters of which there may be many.

Like the dummy stuff below but without the new lines (new lines added to make it easier for you to see what i mean) also the randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 is actually random stuff between the hrefs. There is a differing number of the urls and random junk between the urls that I am interested in:

```
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/theinfoIwant/moreinfoIwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09
Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters
randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/randomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/morerandomtextandornumberthatIdontwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09 
href="/differentinfoIwant/moredifferentinfoIwant/" randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09
Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters
randomjunkincludingspacesandspecialcharacterswithoutausefulpatern _-.,<>:;"azAZ09
```

So here I want to get:

```
/theinfoIwant/moreinfoIwant/
/differentinfoIwant/moredifferentinfoIwant/
```

Comment: Please add some attempts to your question and the programming language, eventually.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all this. It is html, I will try to find again what I have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the regex you are looking for may be something like

```
 href="[^"]*"(?=(?:(?!href=).)*Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters)
```

Where `.` also matches newline (depending the language `/s` flag)

- `href="[^"]*"` matches

  - `href="` followed by
  - any character except `"` as many as possible followed by
  - `"`
- `(?=...)` is a lookahead assertion from the position after closing `"`

  - `(?:(?!href=).)*` is the tempered greedy token (use a negative lookahead to match any character as many as possible ensuring it doesn't contain `href=`)
  - `Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters` the special token

slightly better the `Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters` can also be added in tempered greedy pattern :

```
href="[^"]*"(?=(?:(?!href=|Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters).)*Uniquestringcontainingspecialcharacters)
```